# How to access a FastAPI Depends value from a Pydantic validator?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic, starlette

Let's say I have a route that allows clients to create a new user

(pseudocode)

```py
@app.route("POST")
def create_user(user: UserScheme, db: Session = Depends(get_db)) -> User:
    ...
```

and my `UserScheme` accepts a field such as an `email`. I would like to be able to set some settings (for example `max_length`) globally in a different model `Settings`. How do I access that inside a scheme? I'd like to access the `db` inside my scheme.

So basically my scheme should look something like this (the given code does not work):

```py
class UserScheme(BaseModel):
    email: str

    @validator("email")
    def validate_email(cls, value: str) -> str:
        settings = get_settings(db)  # `db` should be set somehow
        
        if len(value) > settings.email_max_length:
            raise ValueError("Your mail might not be that long")

        return value
```

I couldn't find a way to somehow pass `db` to the scheme. I was thinking about validating such fields (that depend on `db`) inside my route. While this approach works somehow, the error message itself is not raised on the specific field but rather on the entire form, but it should report the error for the correct field so that frontends can display it correctly.

Comment: This question is applicable to FastAPI + Pydantic usage in general, not just in the case of a "scheme". I think a better title could be _How to access a FastAPI Depends value from a Pydantic validator?_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to accept arbitrary JSON objects as input, and then construct a `UserScheme` instance manually inside the route handler:

```py
@app.route(
    "POST",
    response_model=User,
    openapi_extra={
        "requestBody": {
            "content": {
                "application/json": {
                    "schema": UserScheme.schema(ref_template="#/components/schemas/{model}")
                }
            }
        }
    },
)
def create_user(request: Request, db: Session = Depends(get_db)) -> User:
    settings = get_settings(db)
    user_data = request.json()
    user_schema = UserScheme(settings, **user_data)
```

Note that this idea was borrowed from https://stackoverflow.com/a/68815913/2954547, and I have not tested it myself.

---

In order to facilitate the above, you might want to redesign this class so that the `settings` object itself as an attribute on the `UserScheme` model, which means that you don't ever need to perform database access or other effectful operations inside the validator, while also preventing you from instantiating a `UserScheme` without some kind of sensible settings in place, even if they are fallbacks or defaults.

```py
class SystemSettings(BaseModel):
    ...

def get_settings(db: Session) -> SystemSettings:
    ...

EmailAddress = typing.NewType('EmailAddress', st)

class UserScheme(BaseModel):
    settings: SystemSettings
    if typing.TYPE_CHECKING:
        email: EmailAddress
    else:
        email: str | EmailAddress

    @validator("email")
    def _validate_email(cls, value: str, values: dict[str, typing.Any]) -> EmailAddress:
        if len(value) > values['settings'].max_email_length:
            raise ValueError('...')
        return EmailAddress(value)
```

The use of [`tyipng.NewType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#newtype) isn't necessary here, but I think it's a good tool in situations like this. Note that the `typing.TYPE_CHECKING` trick is required to make it work, as per https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/discussions/4823.

Comment: Hey your answer seems to be correct if `Settings` is an input sent by the client. However, `Settings` is not a scheme but rather a model in the database managed by admins. It is not something that the client sends. You can see it as an alternative to environmental variables. Sorry if I wasn't clear in my question. (I'll still upvote your answer as it was my fault not asking my question clearly)

Comment: @Myzel394 my code snippets are intended to demonstrate loading the settings from the database, as in your original example. It's perfectly acceptable (and in fact encouraged) to use Pydantic to represent internal data, _especially_ application configs/settings where you might want sanity checks and sensible default values. There is actually a special base class that supports this case, `BaseConfig`, which inherits from `BaseModel`, but adds features like the ability to parse settings directly from env vars. I omitted that just to keep my sample code simpler.

Comment: My bad, sorry about that. Regarding your snippet, I can't find where "get_settings" is used, could you clarify where to use it?

Comment: @Myzel394 it's used in the `create_user()` function: `settings = get_settings(db)`.