# How to tell FastAPI to get the descriptions from the docstring

Tags: python, fastapi

I want FastAPI to use my docstring.  Is it possible?

This is my code

```
app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/App/test2", tags=['App'])
async def test2(name: str):
    """
    This API returns a simple message.
    :param str name: The name of the person to greet.
    """
    return {"message": "Hello " + name}
```

And this is the swagger page.

[image: swagger page]

and I would prefer to put the "The name of the person to greet." at the bottom, next to the name.

Comment: It _is_ getting the description from the docstring. Per [the docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/path-operation-configuration/?h=docstring#description-from-docstring) it uses the docstring as the (assumed-Markdown) description of the endpoint. But it's not going to parse out _parameter_ descriptions - it doesn't really make sense to write docstrings like that for this kind of function, as it won't be called directly.

Comment: Does this answer your questions? https://stackoverflow.com/a/68815913/8353711

Comment: Is `test2(name: Annotated[str, Query(description="The name of the person to greet.")]:` undesirable?